# How can I run an OpenVPN client on a server while still having access to both networks?

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

I have a server that I want to connect normally to a different OpenVPN server using `openvpn`. The problem is that this makes my client server inaccessible because it's no longer listening to any ports since it has a different external IP.

What would be the correct way to solve this? Is there a way to make the OpenVPN connection on a different interface or something and then have programs I want to use the OpenVPN connection with use said interface? Is something like this possible at all?

Comment: You problem is routing. Review docs related to routing.

Comment: "*My client server*"... which; openvpn client, or openvpn server?

Answer (score 1):

when you start the openvpn client connection, your client and server put up a tun/tap interface with a different IP range than the usual networks for them.

## Server side:

- You must tell the server in the openvpn config file that push to the client the routes to reach the server network.

  > push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0" for example.
- You have to enable ip_forwarding in the server (not in the client) and tell with iptables that the packages going to your client network must be bridged from normal interface to tun/tap interface (in the server).

I hope this help, the problem is on your server, not on your client.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Your OpenVPN server is using the

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

option in its OpenVPN config. This means that it tells all clients to route all their traffic via the VPN.

This means that when the server is accessed, the inbound packets from the client come via the server's external IP and from its normal Internet connection.

However, outgoing packets go through the new default gateway, which goes through the VPN. If the VPN server uses NAT on packets coming from the OpenVPN client, the reply packets will be dropped, because they do not belong to any existing TCP connection established with NAT on the OpenVPN server.

One solution is to remove the option on the server, and then provide specific routes for IP addresses that need to be accessed via the VPN. The command to do this is this:

```
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

This routes all traffic on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet via the VPN. All other traffic is sent using the normal connection.

Another option is to change the DNS entry for the server to point to the IP address of the VPN server, and then you configure port forwarding / DNAT on the VPN server to forward traffic for desired ports to the VPN client.

When using the latter option, all incoming requests to the server will flow through the VPN to the server.

- Tero